# How to disable functions in parent wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm making a child theme to the Twentyfifteen theme in wordpress. The theme has a function in it's functions.php that I wan't to remove:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 825, 510, true );
```

I can remove it from the parents functions.php but I don't want that because I wan't the parent to be untouched. Does anyone know how to do this.

(I wan't to remove it, not change it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress, your theme either supports thumbnails, or it doesn't.

If you **do not** want to support thumbnails (now called featured images), then add the following to your functions.php:

```
remove_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Then the `set_post_thumbnail_size()` in Twentyfifteen will have no effect.

If you **do** want to support thumbnails, then you can choose your own thumbnail size. Just run `set_post_thumbnail_size()` again in your functions.php to set it to what you want it to be:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( width, height, cropOrNot );
```

Note that the only reason to set post thumbnail size is to set a default.

WordPress as installed has 4 default image sizes ('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large' and 'full'). 'full' is the original image, while the others are set in **Settings > Media**.

All set_featured_image_size() does is add an additional size named 'post-thumbnail'.

When you retrieve a post thumbnail, for example with `the_post_thumbnail()`, it will by default return the 'post-thumbnail' size of the image. However, the various functions for retrieving post thumbnails allow you to specify any size you want. For example, if you want to use the original image size for your featured image, you can get it by:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
```

Comment: So what if I wan't the post thumbnail size to preserve the actual size of the original picture even if it is 2000px wide or 40px wide. Shall I then set set_post_thumbnail_size() to a very big number like 10000px or will this strech all post thumbnails to this witdh?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do that. To avoid a long comment, I added to the original answer.